# accessing Ubuntu from vnc on windows

Tags: windows, vnc, sharing, remmina

I setup desktop sharing on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it works perfectly in conjunction with remmina on another Ubuntu box from inside and outside the building but when someone tries from a vnc viewer on a Windows box. What am I missing?

Comment: " but when someone tries from a vnc viewer on a Windows box."  then what?  Seems like you left out the problem.

Comment: crap shouldn't post in the middle of wanting to destroy everything in sight. Windows boxes can't connect at all even internally doesn't seem to matter if I use a vnc password or not on any port I set with the firewall enabled or disabled it continuously rejects the connection.